# Add photo to a Page album

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I have a Page named "Foo".
I have an app.
I can publish a photo to the app's album on the user's profile, it works fine.
But I'm trying to upload a photo to a "Foo" page album, and it doesn't work.

my as3 code :

```
values = {
  message:facebookMessage, 
  fileName:'Foo' + now.toDateString(), 
  image:bitmap_data
  };
Facebook.api('/333446003374785/photos', handleUploadComplete,
  values, 'POST');
```

Any idea ?

Comment: It'll be great if you'll provide any errors from API you get...

Comment: Thks for your answer. I have this error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]